# Newly created item field values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When creating a new item; is there any way to access all the field values that are set.

Since I'm using `Entity.GetModifiedMembers()` method to access the values of the fields that are changed when updating for logging purposes, the purpose is to have the equivalent result through an entity when creating, like a method `Entity.GetSetMembers()`.

So in general, all I need is a key-value pair with "member name" and "value" items.

**Example:**

```
public class SomethingEntity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime Created {get;set;}
    public DateTime Modified {get;set;}
}

public Dictionary<string, string> GetFieldsAndValuesOfCreatedItem(object entity)
{
    //This is what I need, that can take all the objects from an entity and give
    //the property-value pairs for the object instance
    return RequieredMethod(entity);
}

public ExampleMethod()
{
    var newObject = new SomethingEntity() { Name = "SomeName", Created = DateTime.Now };
    Entity.insetOnSubmit(newObject);
    Entity.SubmitChanges();

    var resultList = GetFieldsAndValuesOfCreatedItem(newObject);

    foreach (var propertyKeyValue in resultList)
    {
        var propertyString = "Property Name: " + propertyKeyValue.Key;
        var valueString = "Value : " + propertyKeyValue.Value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is new, I guess all of the them, no?

Comment: I've found this: item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |                                                                BindingFlags.Public |                                                                BindingFlags.Instance); But I can't get the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that, Reflection is the answer for that as far as I could find: so here is the method I've come up with:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetFieldsAndValuesOfCreatedItem(object item)
{
    var propertyInfoList = item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                            BindingFlags.Public |
                                                            BindingFlags.Instance);

    var list = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfoList)
    {
        var valueObject = propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);
        var value = valueObject != null ? valueObject.ToString() : string.Empty;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            list.Add(propertyInfo.Name, value);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```